# remove a set of characters from a .txt file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a **text file** (more then 1GB in size) and it contains lines like these:

```
10830110bcdf9002a6ade209c5cafbc02e90f84696b04c166c7029c427d1ef4a56580dbbce84a0574ba1fc17c8035ccec4679e5dcb6a6a331ebdb15d6cc0661378f409c3
1083021106e581c71003b987a75f18543cf5858b9fcfc5e04c0dddd79cd18764a865ba86d027de6d1900dc171e4d90a0564abbce99b812b821bd0d7d37aad72ead19c17
10840110dbd43121ef0c51a8ba62193eac247f57f1909e270eeb53d68da60ad61519f19cfb0511ec2431ca54e2fcabf6fa985615ec06def5ba1b753e8ad96d0564aa4c
1084011028375c62fd132d5a4e41ffef2419da345b6595fba8a49b5136de59a884d878fc9789009843c49866a0dc97889242b9fb0b8c112f1423e3b220bc04a2d7dfbdff
10880221005f0e261be654e4c52034d8d05b5c4dc0456b7868763367ab998b7d5886d64fbb24efd14cea668d00bfe8048eb8f096c3306bbb31aaea3e06710fa8c0bb8fca71
108501103461fca7077fc2f0d895048606b828818047a64611ec94443e52cc2d39c968363359de5fc76df48e0bf3676b73b1f8fea5780c2af22c507f83331cc0fbfe6ea9
1085022100a4ce8a09d1f28e78530ce940d6fcbd3c1fe2cb00e7b212b893ce78f8839a11868281179b4f2c812b8318f8d3f9a598b4da750a0ba6054d7e1b743bb67896ee62
1086022100638681ade4b306295815221c5b445ba017943ae59c4c742f0b1442dae4902a56d173a6f859dc6088b6364224ec17c4e2213d9d3c96bd9992b696d7c13b234b50
```

and I have these **strings**:

```
10830110
1083021
10840110
10840110
1088022100
10850110
1085022100
1086022100
```

I need to remove these strings from the beginning of each line in the text file, so the end result is saved to a new file and the lines above will look like these:

```
bcdf9002a6ade209c5cafbc02e90f84696b04c166c7029c427d1ef4a56580dbbce84a0574ba1fc17c8035ccec4679e5dcb6a6a331ebdb15d6cc0661378f409c3
106e581c71003b987a75f18543cf5858b9fcfc5e04c0dddd79cd18764a865ba86d027de6d1900dc171e4d90a0564abbce99b812b821bd0d7d37aad72ead19c17
dbd43121ef0c51a8ba62193eac247f57f1909e270eeb53d68da60ad61519f19cfb0511ec2431ca54e2fcabf6fa985615ec06def5ba1b753e8ad96d0564aa4c
28375c62fd132d5a4e41ffef2419da345b6595fba8a49b5136de59a884d878fc9789009843c49866a0dc97889242b9fb0b8c112f1423e3b220bc04a2d7dfbdff
5f0e261be654e4c52034d8d05b5c4dc0456b7868763367ab998b7d5886d64fbb24efd14cea668d00bfe8048eb8f096c3306bbb31aaea3e06710fa8c0bb8fca71
3461fca7077fc2f0d895048606b828818047a64611ec94443e52cc2d39c968363359de5fc76df48e0bf3676b73b1f8fea5780c2af22c507f83331cc0fbfe6ea9
a4ce8a09d1f28e78530ce940d6fcbd3c1fe2cb00e7b212b893ce78f8839a11868281179b4f2c812b8318f8d3f9a598b4da750a0ba6054d7e1b743bb67896ee62
638681ade4b306295815221c5b445ba017943ae59c4c742f0b1442dae4902a56d173a6f859dc6088b6364224ec17c4e2213d9d3c96bd9992b696d7c13b234b50
```

Comment: Your examples removed to EOL (End Of Line) don't make sense. Perhaps double check them or clarify the criteria. For example line 2.

Comment: @maa please [edit] your question to make it clearer - we shouldn't need to look in comments to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: It looks like the prefix of each of these lines is a fixed length, namely 8 characters long. You can do this easily using the cut command.  `cut -c9- myfile.txt > newfile.txt` The -c means cut-character based, 9- means position all characters on a line from position 9 included to the end of the line.

Comment: @ jawtheshark
 7,8,10  characters   (1083021,10840110,1086022100) so it not work [cut -c9- myfile.txt > newfile.txt]   please suggest

Comment: Is there a way to know what the first characters are?  If not, your task is pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, you have a file called `file1` that contains lines like so:

```
10830110bcdf9002a6ade209c5cafbc02e90f84696b04c166c7029c427d1ef4a56580dbbce84a0574ba1fc17c8035ccec4679e5dcb6a6a331ebdb15d6cc0661378f409c3
1083021106e581c71003b987a75f18543cf5858b9fcfc5e04c0dddd79cd18764a865ba86d027de6d1900dc171e4d90a0564abbce99b812b821bd0d7d37aad72ead19c17
10840110dbd43121ef0c51a8ba62193eac247f57f1909e270eeb53d68da60ad61519f19cfb0511ec2431ca54e2fcabf6fa985615ec06def5ba1b753e8ad96d0564aa4c
1084011028375c62fd132d5a4e41ffef2419da345b6595fba8a49b5136de59a884d878fc9789009843c49866a0dc97889242b9fb0b8c112f1423e3b220bc04a2d7dfbdff
10880221005f0e261be654e4c52034d8d05b5c4dc0456b7868763367ab998b7d5886d64fbb24efd14cea668d00bfe8048eb8f096c3306bbb31aaea3e06710fa8c0bb8fca71
108501103461fca7077fc2f0d895048606b828818047a64611ec94443e52cc2d39c968363359de5fc76df48e0bf3676b73b1f8fea5780c2af22c507f83331cc0fbfe6ea9
1085022100a4ce8a09d1f28e78530ce940d6fcbd3c1fe2cb00e7b212b893ce78f8839a11868281179b4f2c812b8318f8d3f9a598b4da750a0ba6054d7e1b743bb67896ee62
1086022100638681ade4b306295815221c5b445ba017943ae59c4c742f0b1442dae4902a56d173a6f859dc6088b6364224ec17c4e2213d9d3c96bd9992b696d7c13b234b50
```

and a file called `file2` that contains lines like so:

```
10830110
1083021
10840110
10840110
1088022100
10850110
1085022100
1086022100
```

and you want to create a new file called `file3` that contains each line from `file1` minus (from the beginning of each line) the string in the matching line in `file2` like so:

```
bcdf9002a6ade209c5cafbc02e90f84696b04c166c7029c427d1ef4a56580dbbce84a0574ba1fc17c8035ccec4679e5dcb6a6a331ebdb15d6cc0661378f409c3
106e581c71003b987a75f18543cf5858b9fcfc5e04c0dddd79cd18764a865ba86d027de6d1900dc171e4d90a0564abbce99b812b821bd0d7d37aad72ead19c17
dbd43121ef0c51a8ba62193eac247f57f1909e270eeb53d68da60ad61519f19cfb0511ec2431ca54e2fcabf6fa985615ec06def5ba1b753e8ad96d0564aa4c
28375c62fd132d5a4e41ffef2419da345b6595fba8a49b5136de59a884d878fc9789009843c49866a0dc97889242b9fb0b8c112f1423e3b220bc04a2d7dfbdff
5f0e261be654e4c52034d8d05b5c4dc0456b7868763367ab998b7d5886d64fbb24efd14cea668d00bfe8048eb8f096c3306bbb31aaea3e06710fa8c0bb8fca71
3461fca7077fc2f0d895048606b828818047a64611ec94443e52cc2d39c968363359de5fc76df48e0bf3676b73b1f8fea5780c2af22c507f83331cc0fbfe6ea9
a4ce8a09d1f28e78530ce940d6fcbd3c1fe2cb00e7b212b893ce78f8839a11868281179b4f2c812b8318f8d3f9a598b4da750a0ba6054d7e1b743bb67896ee62
638681ade4b306295815221c5b445ba017943ae59c4c742f0b1442dae4902a56d173a6f859dc6088b6364224ec17c4e2213d9d3c96bd9992b696d7c13b234b50
```

That can be done in bash like so:

```bsh
while read p; do
        read l <&4
        n=${l#"$p"}
        echo "${n}" >> file3
        done <"file2" 4<"file1"
```

---

On the other hand, if you do not have `file2` and instead you have a set of strings like `10830110, 1083021 ... and 1086022100` that you would like to delete any of them when it occurs in the beginning of any line in `file1` and save the modified lines to a new file called `file3` then it can be done with sed like so:

```
sed 's/^10830110\|^1083021\|^10840110\|^10840110\|^1088022100\|^10850110\|^1085022100\|^1086022100//g' file1 > file3
```

Comment: file1 -was more than 1 GB , each line independent lines,each line starting like any one of the below content------- 10830110, 1083021, 10840110, 10840110, 1088022100, 10850110, 1085022100, 1086022100 (it is not file2) , the result will like file3 (is correct). how to do with large files?   awk sed cut and python any command will work for remove or replace the content(string)

Comment: @maa I updated the answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you Very Very Much Sir.... It's Working Fine..(this is what i expected.....)    Thank you Once  Again..

Comment: Done sed 's/^10830110\|^1083021\|^10840110\|^10840110\|^1088022100\|^10850110\|^1085022100\|^1086022100//g' file1 > file3 Thank you